# Network issues connecting to VM on Gcloud

Tags: networking, google-compute-engine, gcloud

Is anyone else experiencing issues connecting with their VM on Gcloud? Mine is based in zone asia-east1-b with the IP address 130.211.252.134. When I try a traceroute to it there are a bunch or routers at Google that don't respond. It's been like this for 24 hours. Try it yourself here: https://tools.keycdn.com/traceroute

Comment: FYI: routers are not required to respond to traceroutes. That by itself does not indicate a problem. The ICMP protocol is mostly for debugging connectivity problems and supporting ICMP is optional.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Adding more information to John's comment, for this type of issue, it would be best to check the [Google Cloud Status Dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/) for a real time status update of GCP Services; or for a more certain answer, contact the support team directly using the contact information in the same website and they should be able to investigate if it is an issue on the back end or just specific on your VM.

Comment: Thanks Alex. It has resolved itself now. Strangely, there is no way to directly contact Gcloud from my account even though I pay them around $400 a month. They ask me to upgrade to a paid montlhy support fee which I don't want to do.

Comment: Even Free trial users have free support as can be seen [here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6282346?hl=en). If issue still persists on your end in reaching support, try using this [link](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub/).

Comment: When I follow any of those links such as "File a Case" it just sends me off to this page: https://console.cloud.google.com/support/offerings

Comment: Make sure you are logged in to your account and you can use the **Get billing support**.

Comment: Thanks Alez. I'll try Billing Support next time.